# Creating Different Deck Objects

Tags: java, for-loop

During a test case, if I am trying to call upon methods (placeOnTop() for example), which should test which deck the card is from. I am not sure how this constructor is labeling/ or if at all creating different types of decks...

```
public class StandardDeck implements Deck {
    List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();
    public StandardDeck() {
        for (Suit suit : Suit.values()) {
            for (int rank = 1; rank <= 13; rank++) {
                Card e = new StandardCard(suit, rank, this);
                cards.add(e);
            }
        }
    }


    public void placeOnTop(Card c) {
        cards.add(0, c);
    }
    public Card takeTop() {
        return cards.remove(0);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no 'labeled' field but every time you call `StandardDeck()` will return a new StandardDeck object which holds its very own cards object, which is of type List.

Comment: Say this is the test called on.................................                      Deck d1 = new StandardDeckImpl();
  Deck d2 = new StandardDeckImpl();

  Card card_from_d1 = d1.takeTop();
  Card card_from_d2 = d2.takeTop();

Comment: Show me your constructor for StandardDeckImpl

Comment: Then d1 and d2 are separate instances of StandardDeck and each carry their own unique cards property.

Comment: yes, so for the constructor of StandardDeck(), it should be assigning different memory allocations for said decks. The placeOnTop should be making sure that the card being placed on top is from the same deck.

Comment: then if(c.myDeck == this) will guard that. Change myDeck to some public field or method that recalls the `this` argument to `new StandardCard(suit, rank, this);`

Comment: Where exactly should I put the MyDeck field? Inside the constructor? Before it?

Comment: myDeck should be public within your StandardCard class, and your constructor for StandardCard should include `myDeck = newDeck` where newDeck is the variable name of the third parameter.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28777/discussion-between-fish-and-montycarlo)